# python Ridge regression interpreting results

Tags: python, regression

I am using python with sklearn and statsmodels to create a regression model. 
This is the first time I used the Ridge regression. However, I don't understand what the results mean. For example.

When I print

```
print reg.intercept_
print reg.coef_
```

The out put I get is

```
print  reg.intercept_

[[  0.00000000e+00]
 [ -5.27579034e-03]
 [  3.35202990e-03]
 [ -1.54862324e-02]
 [ -3.74392708e-02]

print reg.coef_   

[ 1.00000000e+00   4.11548523e-02   6.98464464e-01   3.88878487e-01
       5.20562949e+01 ]
```

Whenever, I do a normal linear regression I would only get 1 intercept however in the ridge model I get 5. Can anyone elaborate why and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have multiple targets, if you look at the documentation for [Linear Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression) under the attributes `intercept_` it specifies it's independent of the model. If you look at the same documentation for [Ridge Regression,](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html) it specifies in the Attributes section that  `intercept_ : float | array, shape = (n_targets,)`.

You can verify this by changing the number of targets controlled by the  variable `n_targets` in the following code that I modified:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
import numpy as np

n_targets=2
n_samples, n_features = 10, 5

np.random.seed(0)
y = np.random.randn(n_samples,n_targets)
X = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)
clf = Ridge(alpha=1.0)
clf.fit(X, y) 

print( clf.intercept_)
```

If you set `n_targets=1` you get 0.89586534, if you set `n_targets=2` you get [ 0.7101951   0.36420037].
I cover  Ridge Regression in my course [Data Analysis with Python](https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/data-analysis-python/)./